# How to add a right click action (not menu) to QTableWidget's cells

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I currently have one QTableWidget with different cells. When I left-click on a cell I want the number on it to be increased by 1, and if I right-click I want the number to be decreased by 1.

For the first part there is no problem as I use

```
self.(widget_name).cellClicked.connect(self.addone)
```

The problem comes with the right click. Is there a built in method for this? How can I achieve it? I tried creating my own Table class from QTableWidgets and overriding the mousePressEvent but didn't work (clicking around the cells doesn't do anything, it doesn't even select the cells). Also tried eventFilter and nothing. See below for the exact code I used in both situations.

For mousePressEvent:

```
class Table(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QTableWidget.__init__(self,parent)

    def mousePressEvent(self,QMouseEvent):
        if QMouseEvent.button() == QtCore.LeftButton:
            print('left') #FOR DEBUGGING
            row = self.currentRow()
            column = self.currentColumn()
            new_text = round(float(self.item(row,column).text()) + 1,2)
            self.item(row,column).setText(str(new_text))          

        elif event.button() == QtCore.RightButton:
            print('right') #FOR DEBUGGING
            row = self.currentRow()
            column = self.currentColumn()
            new_text = round(float(self.item(row,column).text()) - 1,2)
            self.item(row,column).setText(str(new_text))
```

For eventFilter:

```
class Table(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QTableWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self,QObject,event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            if event.button() == QtCore.LeftButton:
                print('left') #FOR DEBUGGING
                row = self.currentRow()
                column = self.currentColumn()
                new_text = round(float(self.item(row,column).text()) + 1,2)
                self.item(row,column).setText(str(new_text))          

            elif event.button() == QtCore.RightButton:
                print('right') #FOR DEBUGGING
                row = self.currentRow()
                column = self.currentColumn()
                new_text = round(float(self.item(row,column).text()) - 1,2)
                self.item(row,column).setText(str(new_text))
```

For both (to create the table)

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        ....
        self.parameters = Table(self.centralwidget)
        ...
...
```

The debugging text (printing 'left' or 'right') doesn't appear in the console as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you overwrite a method it always calls the parent's method since it could be doing other kinds of tasks and you would be omitting it. On the other hand if we do that, the delegate would be activated to edit the texts, and that is what is not wanted, so we establish a new delegate that no publisher returns as I show below:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class ReadOnlyDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return

class Table(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setItemDelegate(ReadOnlyDelegate(self))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            it = self.itemAt(event.pos())
            new_text = round(float(it.text()) + 1,2)
            it.setText(str(new_text))          

        elif event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            it = self.itemAt(event.pos())
            new_text = round(float(it.text()) - 1,2)
            it.setText(str(new_text))     
        QtWidgets.QTableWidget.mousePressEvent(self, event)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        table = Table(5, 5)
        self.setCentralWidget(table)
        for i in range(5):
            for j in range(5):
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("{}".format(i*j))
                table.setItem(i, j, item)

if __name__=='__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly, but I don't understand why. Would it be possible for you to please explain it a bit more in depth? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @LeonBrasero 
What part of my answer do you not understand?

Comment: "the delegate would be activated to edit the texts, and that is what is not wanted, so we establish a new delegate that no publisher returns as I show below:" I assume that the delegate is the code I create to overwrite the paren'ts method, but I don't understand the rest of this sentence. Thanks again eyllanesc.

Comment: @LeonBrasero 
The delegate is not the code I did to overwrite the parents, check the following to understand:http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html, the delegate is `class ReadOnlyDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate): ...` and `self.setItemDelegate(ReadOnlyDelegate(self))`

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
class Table(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            print('left')                 # FOR DEBUGGING
            row = self.currentRow()
            column = self.currentColumn()
            new_text = round(float(self.item(row,column).text()) + 1,2)
            self.item(row,column).setText(str(new_text))          

        elif event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            print('right')                 # FOR DEBUGGING
            row = self.currentRow()
            column = self.currentColumn()
            new_text = round(float(self.item(row,column).text()) - 1,2)
            self.item(row,column).setText(str(new_text))
```

Comment: The only changes are the event.button() and the QtCore.Qt. right? I tried it indeed but still not working, not even printing the debugs. Also, as a note: I've seen that I incorrectly put in the OP QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem in the __init__ when it should be QtWidgets.QTableWidget. Just fixed that (and edited the OP) but still not working :(

Comment: Correction: It DOES print the debugging text now, but nothing else, it doesn't even select the cell where I clicked. Thanks! step by step!

Comment: Correction 2: I just discovered that if I just click in a cell nothing happens, BUT if I click in one cell and drag the mouse a little bit within itself, the cell will get sort-of-selected (so the background doesnt change to blue as usual but stays white, but the frame of the cell turns to dots as if it was indeed selected). After that if I click anywhere in the table it does add or substract to the number.